# Pandas value_counts: meaning of number above column of counts

Tags: python, pandas

I have the outputs below from a value_counts on different columns in a pandas dataframe.  The columns contain blank strings.  I'd like to know what the number above the column of counts stands for.  I can't seem to find an answer.

EDIT:  Original dataframe columns are hard to share as it has something like 30 entries and 470 empty entries.  In case a sample helps, here is one part of the column:

```
190       
191    June   
192        
193    May   
194    Apr

195    May
196       
197    Feb
198    Oct
199    Jan
200    Jul
201    Dec
202    May
203    Sep
204    Mar
205    Jan
206    Oct
207    Aug
208    Sep
209    Jul
210    Aug
211    Apr
212    Jul
213    Jul
214    Sep
215       
216    Nov
```

I have also tried to replicate the situation but don't get a number above the column of counts:

```
b = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8], 'col2': [3, 4, 4, 5, 5, np.nan, ""]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=b)
df3['col2'].value_counts()
```

[image]

Code used for each output:

```
return FullDatesDF["Month2"].value_counts()
return FullDatesDF["Month3"].value_counts()
```

and the output

[image]

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: please post your df not image

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**. This includes a sample input dataframe as text (no images / links).

Comment: the df is too large.  I am trying to replicate the error but not having much success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have values that are not nulls, but for example strings like ' '.

Value_counts() excludes NA values automatically, but if there's something (like space) it will count it.

**Edit:**

If "" is your most frequent value it will appear on top, looking like a column name.

You said that your df has around 470 empty entries and that matches the numbers you got on top.

Another way to look at it:

```
""     468
7      5
9      4
...
Name: Month3b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.  You are spot on.